# WordPress - Cannot login after migrating with All-in-one WP Migration

Tags: php, wordpress, database-migration

I have just used All-in-one WP Migration plugin to transfer my website onto another server with new domain. The problem is after the migration no accounts seem to work when logging in on `/wp-admin` or `/wp-login`. Neither the default account the fresh WP installation had, nor the accounts that were migrated with the site.

The problem is i cannot access database tonight, is there any way to make that work? Maybe plugin sets new admin account, anybody knows?

Comment: I have used the All-in-one plugin to migrate sites and have not run into this issue. It does not set a new admin. It copies over all of your users from the old site. If you added a new user to the new site before the migration that user **will have been deleted** when you migrated. Importing the migration file replaces the entire database. Are you relying on autofill passwords?

Comment: @MrGlass Damn, seems like some part might have been corrupted then, maybe its encoding issue, but i suppose WP has utf-8 set as default db encoding right? So it should match each other

Comment: I think WP has a encoding setting in config.php file. You should also check the DB encoding that was used to create the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the databasename and password of the wordpress install you can insert a new user with mysql.

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Your Name', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.test.com/', '2011-06-07 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Name');

INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: I tried all the answers on every thread and this is the _only_ one that fixed it for me.
It happens everytime if export/import with the migration plugin mentioned by the OP.